# Fetch record if found match of one comma separated record with another comma separated records

Tags: mysql, group-concat, find-in-set

I have 3 tables

1. `user`
2. `service`
3. `userServices`

**User Table**

```
Id  |  Name   | Status
------------------------
1   |  User1  | y
2   |  User2  | y
3   |  User3  | y
4   |  User4  | y
```

**Service Table**

```
Id  |  ServiceName   | Status
------------------------
1   |  Service1      | y
2   |  Service2      | y
3   |  Service3      | y
4   |  Service4      | y
```

**User Service Table**

```
Id  |  UserId   | ServiceId   | Status
-----------------------------------------
1   |  1        | 1           | y
2   |  1        | 3           | y
3   |  1        | 2           | y
4   |  1        | 4           | y
5   |  2        | 2           | y
6   |  2        | 3           | y
7   |  2        | 4           | y
8   |  3        | 1           | y
9   |  3        | 3           | y
10  |  3        | 4           | y
11  |  3        | 2           | y
```

I will get service id as comma separated string like `1,2,3` as the input & I need to check that which user provide this all services.

For example; 
User 1 provides services 1,3,2,4, and 1,2,3 is subset of 1,3,2,4 so this record should be returned.

User 2 provide services 2,3,4, so 1,2,3 is not subset of 2,3,4 then this record should not be returned.

I have tried using `FIND_IN_SET with GROUP_CONCAT` of user's id but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can the **User Service Table** contain duplicates?

If not, you can try

```
SELECT UserId FROM userServices 
WHERE serviceId IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY UserId HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

( replace `1,2,3` with the input and `3` with number of groups in input, or you could even calculate it in the SQL itself)

Comment: thanks for your help.., but sorry what do you mean by number of group?

Comment: Amount of service is in input, for 1,2,3 it's 3, for 1,3,5,7,9 it's 5